# Oracle ORA-22295 4000 Byte limit

Tags: oracle

Can anybody explain why I would get this Oracle error...

```
ORA-22295: cannot bind more than 4000 bytes data to LOB and LONG columns in 1 statement
```

...when doing the below query?  There are 1000 7-digit numbers in the IN clause.  When there are 949 7-digit numbers, the error does not occur.  I don't know what happens if the number of IN clause values is 950-999.  If the numbers are 6-digits, it works fine with 1000 numbers.  I assume the IN clause is hitting a 4000 bytes wall but I'm not sure how its determined. Column CLUSTER_EVENT_ID is defined as a number and there are no LOB or LONG columns in the table.

```
SELECT t0.CLUSTER_EVENT_ID, t0.BROADCAST_TYPE, t0.CLUSTER_ID, t0.CREATED_BY, t0.CREATION_DATE, t0.EVENT_DATA, t0.RESPONSE, t0.
SOURCE_ID, t0.STATUS, t0.EVENT_TYPE FROM CC_CLUSTER_EVENT t0 WHERE (t0.CLUSTER_EVENT_ID IN (9076854,   9076856,   9076932,
9076935,   9076940,   9077002,   9077024,   9077028,   9077131,   9077135,   9077139,   9077162,   9077220,   9077273,   9077305,   9077308,   9077318,
9077321,   9077331,   9077340,   9077366,   9077484,   9077560,   9077586,   9077589,   9077633,   9077637,   9077646,   9077704,   9077707,   9077837,
9077927,   9077980,   9078008,   9078012,   9078064,   9078072,   9078108,   9078110,   9078141,   9078143,   9078144,   9078156,   9078228,   9078234,
9078289,   9078418,   9078604,   9078605,   9076851,   9076924,   9077022,   9077163,   9077278,   9077330,   9077369,   9077371,   9077418,   9077457,
9077460,   9077548,   9077584,   9077590,   9077651,   9077657,   9077805,   9077810,   9077813,   9077825,   9077831,   9078018,   9078063,   9078103,
9078114,   9078146,   9078159,   9078233,   9078237,   9078288,   9078471,   9078513,   9078518,   9078565,   9078643,   9078657,   9076887,   9076893,
9076937,   9077012,   9077016,   9077031,   9077138,   9077164,   9077167,   9077263,   9077272,   9077304,   9077312,   9077313,   9077317,   9077403,
9077412,   9077453,   9077486,   9077489,   9077494,   9077559,   9077599,   9077625,   9077741,   9077809,   9077823,   9077836,   9077889,   9077891,
9077896,   9077928,   9077965,   9078076,   9078329,   9078375,   9078404,   9078473,   9078475,   9078480,   9078519,   9078562,   9078567,   9078572,
9078651,   9076852,   9076900,   9076969,   9077004,   9077009,   9077026,   9077029,   9077063,   9077073,   9077075,   9077274,   9077277,   9077333,
9077376,   9077451,   9077591,   9077595,   9076846,   9076928,   9076961,   9077040,   9077062,   9077067,   9077123,   9077130,   9077171,   9077271,
9077319,   9077323,   9077328,   9077600,   9077626,   9077635,   9077639,   9077642,   9077649,   9077658,   9077703,   9077743,   9077751,   9077817,
9077829,   9078005,   9078010,   9078015,   9078016,   9078152,   9078153,   9078157,   9078160,   9078181,   9078185,   9078194,   9078238,   9078283,
9078332,   9078339,   9078363,   9078379,   9078403,   9078420,   9078564,   9078568,   9078578,   9078579,   9078613,   9078645,   9078656,   9078658,
9078660,   9076883,   9076889,   9076897,   9077033,   9077036,   9077076,   9077134,   9077166,   9077262,   9077338,   9077370,   9077641,   9077746,
9077802,   9077815,   9077964,   9078184,   9078223,   9078232,   9078327,   9078340,   9078508,   9078563,   9078573,   9076845,   9076927,   9076966,
9076971,   9076977,   9076979,   9077005,   9077021,   9077023,   9077132,   9077172,   9077203,   9077215,   9077267,   9077495,   9077543,   9077553,
9077556,   9077558,   9077581,   9077653,   9077702,   9077747,   9077832,   9077893,   9077924,   9077931,   9077975,   9078017,   9078067,   9078071,
9078150,   9078154,   9078286,   9078324,   9078330,   9078402,   9078413,   9078479,   9078506,   9078659,   9076848,   9076896,   9076898,   9076931,
9076980,   9077007,   9077014,   9077079,   9077207,   9077211,   9077301,   9077302,   9077314,   9077326,   9077380,   9077406,   9077413,   9077442,
9077445,   9077483,   9077492,   9077652,   9077716,   9077760,   9077833,   9077894,   9077935,   9077970,   9078002,   9078225,   9078505,   9078607,
9078614,   9078620,   9076881,   9076892,   9076968,   9077039,   9077070,   9077136,   9077173,   9077202,   9077279,   9077316,   9077329,   9077339,
9077377,   9077404,   9077414,   9077450,   9077481,   9077490,   9077497,   9077541,   9077549,   9077628,   9077630,   9077638,   9077644,   9077656,
9077701,   9077714,   9077720,   9077824,   9077830,   9077895,   9077922,   9077923,   9077936,   9077963,   9077968,   9077972,   9077974,   9077979,
9078006,   9078011,   9078062,   9078065,   9078109,   9078142,   9078199,   9078368,   9078376,   9078606,   9078611,   9078644,   9078295,   9078325,
9078338,   9078365,   9078366,   9078370,   9078476,   9078512,   9078575,   9078618,   9078648,   9076857,   9076886,   9076921,   9076938,   9076962,
9077017,   9077032,   9077124,   9077213,   9077266,   9077306,   9077322,   9077401,   9077420,   9077621,   9077640,   9077749,   9077818,   9077822,
9077828,   9077881,   9077888,   9077926,   9078004,   9078020,   9078066,   9078069,   9078118,   9078292,   9076836,   9076866,   9076871,   9076874,
9076981,   9076994,   9077046,   9077057,   9077089,   9077145,   9077146,   9077257,   9077342,   9077424,   9077472,   9077473,   9077502,   9077521,
9077620,   9077665,   9077687,   9077736,   9077782,   9077791,   9077866,   9078136,   9078170,   9078172,   9078208,   9078218,   9078251,   9078266,
9078318,   9078349,   9078421,   9078441,   9078459,   9078494,   9078553,   9078592,   9078623,   9076876,   9076877,   9076901,   9076909,   9076916,
9076920,   9076942,   9076948,   9076983,   9076986,   9076987,   9076992,   9077083,   9077092,   9077095,   9077110,   9077153,   9077154,   9077194,
9077196,   9077226,   9077236,   9077239,   9077288,   9077289,   9077293,   9077346,   9077352,   9077385,   9077395,   9077399,   9077434,   9077563,
9077566,   9077575,   9077612,   9077619,   9077661,   9077669,   9077685,   9077771,   9077778,   9077792,   9077875,   9077878,   9077984,   9078085,
9078097,   9078100,   9078213,   9078246,   9078254,   9078257,   9078270,   9078272,   9078311,   9078314,   9078352,   9078382,   9078391,   9078496,
9078527,   9078673,   9076860,   9076925,   9076967,   9076972,   9076974,   9077020,   9077035,   9077061,   9077161,   9077175,   9077177,   9077180,
9077210,   9077212,   9077214,   9077216,   9077367,   9077408,   9077459,   9077650,   9077711,   9077742,   9077820,   9077821,   9077840,   9077899,
9077940,   9077971,   9078009,   9078013,   9078061,   9078113,   9078115,   9078119,   9078188,   9078300,   9078331,   9078414,   9078461,   9078469,
9078504,   9078570,   9078682,   9076855,   9076929,   9077010,   9077019,   9077034,   9077179,   9077201,   9077206,   9077320,   9077325,   9077361,
9077379,   9077443,   9077448,   9077455,   9077555,   9077583,   9077593,   9077596,   9077598,   9077624,   9077629,   9077631,   9077634,   9077706,
9077712,   9077744,   9077754,   9077801,   9078102,   9078111,   9078112,   9078149,   9078229,   9078236,   9078290,   9078369,   9078406,   9078502,
9078507,   9078561,   9078653,   9078654,   9076890,   9076899,   9076970,   9076973,   9077064,   9077125,   9077208,   9077310,   9077362,   9077405,
9077407,   9077409,   9077416,   9077444,   9077456,   9077482,   9077713,   9077715,   9077753,   9077811,   9077967,   9077976,   9078007,   9078019,
9078104,   9078148,   9078198,   9078227,   9078281,   9078284,   9078321,   9078333,   9078514,   9078603,   9078647,   9078235,   9078378,   9078401,
9078463,   9078501,   9078510,   9078576,   9076850,   9076922,   9076926,   9076933,   9076975,   9077003,   9077006,   9077008,   9077011,   9077027,
9077204,   9077275,   9077315,   9077334,   9077335,   9077373,   9077402,   9077487,   9077500,   9077587,   9077588,   9077622,   9077627,   9077645,
9077647,   9077648,   9077659,   9077660,   9077705,   9077708,   9077710,   9077717,   9077752,   9077758,   9077759,   9077804,   9077925,   9077938,
9077962,   9077973,   9077977,   9078001,   9078003,   9078014,   9078068,   9078077,   9078117,   9078147,   9078155,   9078158,   9078192,   9078239,
9078285,   9078291,   9078296,   9078298,   9078371,   9078467,   9078468,   9078509,   9078516,   9078569,   9078602,   9078609,   9076858,   9076882,
9076884,   9077069,   9077080,   9077121,   9077127,   9077129,   9077168,   9077169,   9077364,   9077415,   9077441,   9077493,   9077557,   9077745,
9077807,   9077882,   9077885,   9077892,   9077930,   9077939,   9078070,   9078120,   9078193,   9078230,   9076894,   9076936,   9076963,   9077128,
9077137,   9077327,   9077336,   9077337,   9077449,   9077597,   9077655,   9077719,   9077748,   9077803,   9077808,   9077814,   9077838,   9077934,
9078074,   9078078,   9078080,   9078116,   9078151,   9078335,   9078336,   9078372,   9078405,   9078411,   9078566,   9078619,   9076844,   9076885,
9076965,   9076978,   9077015,   9077025,   9077072,   9077133,   9077170,   9077176,   9077209,   9077276,   9077311,   9077324,   9077363,   9077374,
9077378,   9077454,   9077458,   9077496,   9077546,   9077755,   9077816,   9077835,   9077884,   9077921,   9077933,   9078101,   9078107,   9078145,
9078196,   9078200,   9078282,   9078287,   9078297,   9078326,   9078373,   9078377,   9078409,   9078416,   9078571,   9078601,   9078608,   9078649,
9078681,   9076832,   9076917,   9077101,   9077427,   9077433,   9077471,   9077476,   9077522,   9077530,   9077536,   9077617,   9077667,   9077680,
9077723,   9077740,   9077762,   9077775,   9077781,   9078047,   9078054,   9078140,   9078163,   9078206,   9078209,   9078220,   9078243,   9078258,
9078273,   9078277,   9078304,   9078312,   9078400,   9078434,   9078449,   9078452,   9078521,   9078538,   9078549,   9078551,   9078586,   9078597,
9078629,   9076849,   9077065,   9077077,   9077165,   9077205,   9077264,   9077307,   9077368,   9077372,   9077411,   9077491,   9077550,   9077551,
9077554,   9077585,   9077594,   9077826,   9077966,   9077969,   9077978,   9078106,   9078183,   9078224,   9078323,   9078361,   9078362,   9078410,
9078412,   9078417,   9078472,   9078520,   9078580,   9078642,   9078652,   9076859,   9076934,   9077261,   9077268,   9077269,   9077303,   9077375,
9077410,   9077419,   9077498,   9077542,   9077547,   9077552,   9077623,   9077632,   9077654,   9077812,   9077827,   9077834,   9077883,   9077886,
9077887,   9077890,   9077929,   9078182,   9078186,   9078191,   9078231,   9078364,   9078477,   9078511,   9078515,   9078574,   9078615,   9078655,
9078187,   9078380,   9078462,   9078478,   9078503,   9078617,   9076888,   9076923,   9076964,   9077018,   9077037,   9077074,   9077178,   9077217,
9077218,   9077270,   9077332,   9077485,   9077544,   9077592,   9077636,   9077643,   9077806,   9077932,   9078073,   9078190,   9078195,   9078197,
9078240,   9078294,   9078322,   9076891,   9076895,   9076930,   9076939,   9077013,   9077066,   9077068,   9077071,   9077078,   9077122,   9077140,
9077174,   9077219,   9077265,   9077280,   9077309,   9077365,   9077417,   9077446,   9077447,   9077452,   9077488,   9077718,   9077819,   9077897,
9077937,   9077961,   9078189,   9078222,   9078293,   9078299,   9078328,   9078334,   9078374,   9078407,   9078408,   9078464,   9078466,   9078577,
9078610,   9078612,   9078616,   9078641,   9078646,   9078650,   9078517,   9076847,   9076853,   9076976,   9077001,   9077030,   9077038,   9077126,
9077499,   9077545,   9077582,   9077709,   9077750,   9077756,   9077757,   9077839,   9077898,   9077900,   9078075,   9078079,   9078105,   9078221,
9078226,   9078337,   9078367))
```

Comment: are there a long column  in you select ?

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems most likely you are breaking Oracle with this incredibly long IN list!

Comment: IN list is limited to 1024 items in Oracle. Try to break it to number of UNION ALLs.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem. I modified the code as follows (I have a copy of the EMP table from the standard SCOTT schema in my own schema): `select * from emp where (deptno in (....))` and I used your list, with all 1000 numbers. It worked fine - it returned no rows since the department numbers are 10, 20 and 30. So, I suspect this may be a problem with your FRONT-END. **How** are you running this? Can you try it in SQL\*Plus?

Comment: @olekb - that is incorrect; the limit is 1000, as the OP stated correctly.

Comment: @mathguy ur right, my bad

Comment: write numbers to a temp table then join with that?

Comment: Do you want to know **why** this error appears ? Or do you rather want to know how to avoid this problem ?

Comment: @scaisEdge - that thread doesn't seem related to the OP's question. The OP has a list of 1000 elements, and indeed the error is not about the number of elements, it is about something else.